# Simultaneous "well-done" description of the complex value of an element and attributes of this element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Can't correctly combine two conditions within XSD schema which would describe:

1) Element's value complexType with restriction

2) Element's attributes' sequence

No one of complexType \ simpleType or whatever constructions which i tried to combine don't want to be "well-done".

***What i desired***

Within one CHILD element:

1) Possibility to specify Element's value (for example max length restriction)

2) Possibility to describe\specify that Element's attributes

**What i have?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ROOT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PARENT">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CHILD"> <!-- extended (complex) description for CHILD's value is needed-->
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="attribute-1" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
                            <xs:attribute name="attribute-2">
                              <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:maxLength value = "64"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                              </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="parent-attribute" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="root-attribute" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

kind of complex-restriction that i would like to extend CHILD's value (as an example)
(note: and keep its attributes' description also)

```
              <xs:element name="CHILD" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="4000"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps: a restriction step to define the extra facets on the value, and then an extension step to permit extra attributes. (You can do the two steps in either order).